# img rollover affects text in same div

Tags: css, hyperlink, image, rollover

I have a div that houses an img and a title that sits below it. There is a hyperlink that wraps around this entire div. How can I make the text-link hover state show when I hover over the image? Here's the html so far:

```
<a href="#"><div id="box" class="image-hover">
<img src="images/image.jpg"></img><p class="title">Title goes here</p></div></a>

CSS:
.image-hover a {background-color: white;}
.image-hover a:hover {background-color: navy;}
.image-hover a:active {background-color: navy;}
```

Comment: Follow the rules of W3C and you will get it right! `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<a>` hyperlink is an inline element. The `<div>` is a block level element. It is not right to put a `div` inside an `a` element. Change your code like replacing `div` with `span` and giving `display: block;` and then try.